# Three tables side by side

Tags: tables, positioning

I have three tables and I need that the three tables stays side by side.

I tried with this approach but the tables are overlapping each other.

```
\begin{table}[!htb]\tiny
    \begin{minipage}{.20\linewidth}
    \caption{First Table}
     \label{tab:first_table}
      \centering
         \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    {\bf Library} & {\bf Comedy} & {\bf Scary} & {\bf Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $23$ & $233$ & $3295$ \\
    Library2 & $843$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    Library3 & $11$ & $1$ & $0$ \\
    Library4 & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \midrule
    {\bf Total} & $878$ & $234$ & $3295$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.20\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{Second Table}
    \label{tab:second_table}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    {\bf Library} & {\bf Comedy} & {\bf Scary} & {\bf Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $954$ & $40$ & $0$ \\
    Library2 & $32$ & $0$ & $1$ \\
    Library3 & $11$ & $132$ & $110$ \\
    Library4 & $1$ & $30$ & $67$ \\
    \midrule
    {\bf Total} & $998$ & $202$ & $178$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}    
      \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.20\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Third Table}
    \label{tab:third_table}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    {\bf Library} & {\bf Comedy} & {\bf Scary} & {\bf Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $483$ & $27$ & $2$ \\
    Library2 & $848$ & $220$ & $3$ \\
    Library3 & $121$ & $12$ & $40$ \\
    Library4 & $13$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \midrule
    {\bf Total} & $1465$ & $250$ & $45$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}    
\end{minipage} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Change `0.2\linewidth` to something larger.

Comment: Please make your code compile by adding a document class, `\begin{document}` etc. That makes it much easier for people to help you (and so much more likely they'll give you useful input).

Comment: I would suggest making the intercolumn spacing a little smaller. Perhaps `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.7\tabcolsep}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're setting the tables in minipages that are less wide than the tables.

Since the tables are in `\tiny` format, it's better to reduce the `\tabcolsep`, which by default is 6pt. Maybe 1pt is too little, experiment.

Note that `\bf` is an obsolete command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\tiny\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{minipage}{.33\linewidth}
\centering

\caption{First Table}
\label{tab:first_table}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Library} & \textbf{Comedy} & \textbf{Scary} & \textbf{Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $23$ & $233$ & $3295$ \\
    Library2 & $843$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    Library3 & $11$ & $1$ & $0$ \\
    Library4 & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Total} & $878$ & $234$ & $3295$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
\centering

\caption{Second Table}
\label{tab:second_table}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Library} & \textbf{Comedy} & \textbf{Scary} & \textbf{Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $954$ & $40$ & $0$ \\
    Library2 & $32$ & $0$ & $1$ \\
    Library3 & $11$ & $132$ & $110$ \\
    Library4 & $1$ & $30$ & $67$ \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Total} & $998$ & $202$ & $178$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}    
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
\centering

\caption{Third Table}
\label{tab:third_table}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Library} & \textbf{Comedy} & \textbf{Scary} & \textbf{Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $483$ & $27$ & $2$ \\
    Library2 & $848$ & $220$ & $3$ \\
    Library3 & $121$ & $12$ & $40$ \\
    Library4 & $13$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Total} & $1465$ & $250$ & $45$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}    
\end{minipage} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I do not know why but it only appears to me the third caption in the first table. Why?

Comment: @user44589 Probably a consequence of your document class, or one of the packages you load.

Comment: I prefer `\dimexpr\linewidth/3\relax` instead of `.33\linewidth`.

Comment: Would it be possible to have single caption for the all three tables?

Comment: @alper Just use a single caption before starting the minipages.

Comment: Sorry for 9 year late comment, is it also possible to have caption starting with `(a) (b) (c)` under main Table caption?

Comment: @alper That's a job for the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Ah :( having `subcaption ` conflicts with other packages on my end: `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \sf@counterlist

l.373 \begin{document}
`  I will ask new question regarding to this thanks

Comment: @alper Well, if you load `subfig`, use it!

Comment: Ah I had `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` (I don't know why), uncommenting it solved the problem I was having :-)

Answer (score 3):

use a correct value for the minipage width and resize the tabulars:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.33\linewidth}
\caption{First Table}  \label{tab:first_table}
 \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    {\bf Library} & {\bf Comedy} & {\bf Scary} & {\bf Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $23$ & $233$ & $3295$ \\
    Library2 & $843$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    Library3 & $11$ & $1$ & $0$ \\
    Library4 & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \midrule
    {\bf Total} & $878$ & $234$ & $3295$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
}%
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.33\linewidth}
  \caption{Second Table}\label{tab:second_table}
 \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
 \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    {\bf Library} & {\bf Comedy} & {\bf Scary} & {\bf Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $954$ & $40$ & $0$ \\
    Library2 & $32$ & $0$ & $1$ \\
    Library3 & $11$ & $132$ & $110$ \\
    Library4 & $1$ & $30$ & $67$ \\
    \midrule
    {\bf Total} & $998$ & $202$ & $178$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.33\linewidth}
 \caption{Third Table} \label{tab:third_table}
 \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    {\bf Library} & {\bf Comedy} & {\bf Scary} & {\bf Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $483$ & $27$ & $2$ \\
    Library2 & $848$ & $220$ & $3$ \\
    Library3 & $121$ & $12$ & $40$ \\
    Library4 & $13$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \midrule
    {\bf Total} & $1465$ & $250$ & $45$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
 }%
\end{minipage} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to keep the column spacing, you could set the tabulars sideways by using a landscape environment. This example also introduces a little horizontal spacing between the tabulars to help keep them separate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[!htb]\scriptsize
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \caption{First Table}
     \label{tab:first_table}
      \centering
         \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    {\bf Library} & {\bf Comedy} & {\bf Scary} & {\bf Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $23$ & $233$ & $3295$ \\
    Library2 & $843$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    Library3 & $11$ & $1$ & $0$ \\
    Library4 & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \midrule
    {\bf Total} & $878$ & $234$ & $3295$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\hspace*{1em}
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{Second Table}
    \label{tab:second_table}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    {\bf Library} & {\bf Comedy} & {\bf Scary} & {\bf Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $954$ & $40$ & $0$ \\
    Library2 & $32$ & $0$ & $1$ \\
    Library3 & $11$ & $132$ & $110$ \\
    Library4 & $1$ & $30$ & $67$ \\
    \midrule
    {\bf Total} & $998$ & $202$ & $178$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}\hspace*{1em}
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Third Table}
    \label{tab:third_table}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    {\bf Library} & {\bf Comedy} & {\bf Scary} & {\bf Others} \\
    \midrule
    Library1 & $483$ & $27$ & $2$ \\
    Library2 & $848$ & $220$ & $3$ \\
    Library3 & $121$ & $12$ & $40$ \\
    Library4 & $13$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \midrule
    {\bf Total} & $1465$ & $250$ & $45$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tabulars set sideways using <code>pdflscape</code>]