# Three Tables side by side with different caption

Tags: tables

I would like to draw three tables side by side with three different captions. My tables are below

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{Common Differentially Expressed and Non Differentially Expressed genes by }
\label{table:6}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline { Method} & { \centering  Differentially Expressed Genes} & {Non differentially Expressed Genes}  \\
\hline Fooooo and AW    & 14923 & 4715   \\
\hline  Fooooo and Fiiiiis  & 14923 & 4715   \\
\hline Fooooo and Fiiiiis  & 12700 & 4720  \\
\hline Fooooo and Fiiiiis & 15179 & 3624 \\
\hline Fooooo and Fiiiiis  & 14904 & 4711  \\
\hline Fooooo and Fiiiiis  & 14904 & 4711  \\
\hline Fooooo and Fiiiiis  & 12682 & 4716  \\
\hline Fooooo and Fiiiiis  & 15159 & 3623 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{Common Differentially Expressed and Non Differentially Expressed genes by }
\label{table:7}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline { Method} & { \centering  Differentially Expressed Genes} & {Non differentially Expressed Genes}  \\
\hline Fooooo and AW    & 15546 & 3889   \\
\hline Fooooo and Fiiiiis   & 15546 & 3889   \\
\hline Fooooo and miiii  & 13296 & 4307  \\
\hline Forgery and minP & 15554 & 1977 \\
\hline Haaaaa and Fffffff  & 15538 & 4071  \\
\hline Haaaaa  and ffffff  & 15538 & 4071  \\
\hline haaaaaaa  and tttt  & 13296 & 4307  \\
\hline haaaaaaa  and ssssss  & 15554 & 1977 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{Common Differentially Expressed and Non Differentially Expressed genes }
\label{table:8}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline { Method} & { \centering  Differentially Expressed Genes} & {Non differentially Expressed Genes}  \\
\hline aaa and BBB  & 10193 & 2060   \\
\hline BBBBB and CCCCC  & 10193 & 2060   \\
\hline CCCCC and DDDDD & 10193 & 360 \\
\hline EEEE and FFFF  & 10177 & 2059  \\
\hline GGG and HHHHH & 10177 & 2059  \\
\hline IIIIIIIII nd JJJJJJ  & 10177 & 360  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In particular, [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155476/215) has separate labels.

Answer (score 0):

Please ask clearly your question.

I suppose you are getting some width problems. Did you try to use resizebox ?

```
    \resizebox{.33\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{}

        \end{tabular}
    }
```